# Error al agregar ciertas librerias en Android Studio, APK META-INF/LICENSE

Tags: java, android-studio

Resulta que estoy pasando una aplicación que hice en java a android pero al copiar las librerias a la carpeta libs de Android al ejecutar la app me sale un error el cual es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto solo pasa con algunas librerias y entiendo yo que dice que estan duplicadas o algo asi..

Me gustaria que me expliquen porque sale este error exactamente y como solucionarlo si es que se puede.

estas son las librerias que agrego al projecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, este error me sale aun sin agregar codigo a la app.

Comment: Procura compartir el log de errores en formato código o cita, ya que la imagen no se puede apreciar con claridad, además de compartir el código con el que estás trabajando y dónde se produce el error

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente tienes archivos duplicados, en tu archivo `app/build.gradle`, agrega la opción sección `packagingOptions`, excluye los archivos:

```
android {

    packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
       exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
       exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

    }
}
```

Comment: Eso he estado intentando pero me tira un error que es el siguiente:   Error:(3, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Analisis'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_6jpdxa0ohwmi50ietfa23w1bh$_run_closure1@74c51a70] on root project 'Analisis' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Bueno lo habia colocado en el build gradle que dice Project, lo coloque en el otro el que dice build gradle (Module: app) pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error que el del inicio...

Comment: Creo que estas agregando incorrectamente las opciones, agrega tu build.gradle de /app y te ayudo a corregirlo.